# SQL Server 2012 database availability design?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Can anyone please suggest me what is the best practice for me to follow when consolidating multiple stand alone DB from SQL Server 2005 - 2008 boxes into just 2x SQL Server 2012 Enterprise nodes in two different sites (1 x physical server in PROD and 1 x physical server in DR with different geographical location and VLANs as well) ?

Because my understanding with SQL Server 2008 R2 (I Installed on top of the MSCS 2008 R2) is that I will need 2 nodes in each site as follows:

PRODSQL1
PRODSQL2

and then

DRSQL1
DRSQL2

respectively.

and the proposed design are as follows:

PRODSQL2012-1
DRSQL2012-1

only.

The problem is that not all of the Tier-1 app database has got Mirorring or Transaction log shipping capability, so I wonder what should I do to avoid major Database outage when I patch the PRODSQL2012-1 ?